# Drawing a focus rectangle only when control receives focus via keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, focus

I want to style a `TabItem`'s "*focus rectangle*". I've learned I can do this using `FocusVisualStyle`. The problem is that [`FocusVisualStyle` creates a sepearate visual tree for an adorner that is drawn on top of the control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx). I use complex semi-transparent controls and drop-shadow effects, and I need to show the rectangle **under** certain elements that are part of the `TabItem.Template`.

I've found on MSDN that I can use [`IsKeyboardFocused` combined with trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx#Alternatives) to achieve what I need. However [further research](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/dec15e4b-bbc5-47b7-ad44-76f039d7b53f) have shown [this is not correct](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/aaf7ec00-8470-4086-86da-2a8c1467bb04/), because:

> Keyboard focus refer to the element that is currently receiveing keyboard input. It doesn't mean the focus is set via a keyboard navigation.

One of the possible workaround might be:

> You can listen to key_down events to check whether an navigation key is pressed. WPF controls do this internally to display the FocusVisualStyle.

**Is there any other, easier way to achieve what I'm trying to do?** I'm not really into creating code behind, listening for events and handling all of these many different navigation keys and shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, FrameworkElement checks what the last input device was in an override for [OnGotKeyboardFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ongotkeyboardfocus.aspx). If the last input device was a keyboard, then it shows the FocusVisualStyle.

You can accomplish the same thing by adding a handler for the GotKeyboardFocus event and checking if `InputManager.Current.MostRecentInputDevice is KeyboardDevice`.

You'd probably want to add an attached dependency property so you can still use a Trigger, say IsFocusVisualVisible. You'd set it to true in your GotKeyboardFocus handler, if the last input device was the keyboard, and set to false in a handler for LostKeyboardFocus.

Comment: So I still need to use code behind for the `TabItem`, right? Is there any other way than to use code behind?

Comment: @Paja - Unfortunately, yes. You'd need some sort of code-behind to check the MostRecentInputDevice property and hook up the event handlers.

Comment: @Paja - Just to clarify, you don't need code-behind "in" the TabItem (i.e. you don't have to create a derived class). You can use an [attached behavior](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it works, somehow... the `GotKeyboardFocus` and `LostKeyboardFocus` are probably wrong events - when I use Tab key to jump from `TabItem` to a `TextBox` (which is content of the `TabItem`), the focus rectangle does not disappear. Or when I use mouse to set focus to that TextBox, and then use Tab to switch to other textbox, the TabItem regains the focus rectangle (even though the second textbox is focused)...

Comment: Ahh, figured it out. I just had to put `if (sendeer == e.OriginalSource)` in the event handlers before any code, and it works... Thanks!